# In celery, what is the appropriate way to pass contextual metadata from sender process to worker when a task is enqueued?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

When any celery task is enqueued I want to add contextual metadata the worker will be able to use.

The following code example works but I would like to have an appropriate celery-style solution.

```py
from celery.signals import before_task_publish, task_prerun

@before_task_publish.connect
def receiver_before_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    task_kwags = body[1]
    metadata = {"foo": "bar"}
    task_kwags['__metadata__'] = metadata

@task_prerun.connect
def receiver_task_pre_run(task_id, task, *args, **kwargs):
    metadata = kwargs['kwargs'].pop('__metadata__', {})
    # metadata == {"foo": "bar"}
```

Comment: Where do the metadata come from? Do you know them (or can infer them) upfront at the time of task definition or only at the time the task is being enqueued?

Comment: Only when enqueued. The data comes from the calling  django request.

Comment: And isn't it possible to modify the task to take the metadata as arguments?

Comment: I do not want the tasks to be modified. My goal is to implement a plugin for structured logging that just works after only minimal configuration. My plugin must pass context from django’s request to the task’s logger without any code change. I have a working proof of concept but the implementation seems too hackish to me. I hope celery have a mechanism for this purpose.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When a task starts in the worker the content of `before_task_publish`'s `header` is in the `**kwargs` of `push_request`.

[celery/app/tasks.py:1000](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/93afcb4870f4064c922ed3375a505fdb5bcaa5af/celery/app/task.py#L1000)

```
    def push_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request_stack.push(Context(*args, **kwargs))
```

Something nice is done in the constructor of `Context`.
`self.__dict__.update()` means we can access the values as `Context(metadata={'foo': 'bar'}).metadata`

[celery/app/tasks.py:99](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/93afcb4870f4064c922ed3375a505fdb5bcaa5af/celery/app/task.py#L99)

```py
class Context(object)
# ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)
```

The task context is accessible from `Task`'s `request` property.

[celery/app/tasks.py:1019](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/93afcb4870f4064c922ed3375a505fdb5bcaa5af/celery/app/task.py#L1019)

```py
class Task(object):
# ...
    def _get_request(self):
        """Get current request object."""
        req = self.request_stack.top
        if req is None:
            # task was not called, but some may still expect a request
            # to be there, perhaps that should be deprecated.
            if self._default_request is None:
                self._default_request = Context()
            return self._default_request
        return req
    request = property(_get_request)
```

Which means the final solution is simply this:

```py
from celery.signals import before_task_publish, task_prerun

@before_task_publish.connect
def receiver_before_task_publish(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    metadata = {"foo": "bar"}
    headers['__metadata__'] = metadata

@task_prerun.connect
def receiver_task_pre_run(task_id, task, *args, **kwargs):
    metadata = getattr(task.request, '__metadata__', {}) 
    # metadata == {"foo": "bar"}
```

Note: `task.request.__metadata__` would also work but it fails if a task was enqueued before the signals are integrated. Safer this way.