# How can I add a customer value to message or header in celery task published by celery beat

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have tried to add following content in celery beat "before_task_publish" signal as below in my task.py file

```
@before_task_publish.connect
def task_before_publish_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    my_data={"foo":"bar"}
    kwargs['request'][1]['my_data']=my_dat
    return kwargs
```

Now in the worker end of task.py I tried to intercept the message using signal "task_received", as below,

```
@task_received.connect
def task_receive_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['request'])
```

Here in the receiver end signals I get the message in kwargs['request'] but not my appended value my_data. May be how I intercept in the celery beat signal is not proper

Comment: I believe the following thread answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660979/in-celery-what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-pass-contextual-metadata-from-sender-p

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to involve signals here. As per [the documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields), you can specify `options` argument when setting beat entries, which can hold any arguments supported by [`apply_async`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async). One of the arguments is `headers` which is what you want I guess.

Comment: my actual value is kind of ID which will be generated and passed on for tracking purpose. I am using newrelic third party tool to do distributed tracing. So I can't put that during the schedule time the life cycle starts only when the beat component put the message into the queue.

Comment: Why don't you then refactor your task to grab that extra information right at the start?

Comment: @DejanLekic How to refactor at the start? Because lets say I have created a schedule every day 5pm and when every cycle is getting started I need to add some ID and other data to message and pass that to the workers . Please let me know if this is supported by celery-beat

Comment: I think task can have extra logic to grab the necessary data based on its arguments... It is not a job of the scheduler to pass different arguments to its tasks. Its job is to run tasks at particular time.